# Compiz Anaglyph plugin problems on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, compiz, 3d

Well, I've had the Compiz Anaglyph plugin installed since I started working with Oneiric.  It's worked SUPERBLY...that is, until I upgraded to Precise.  All the other eyecandy I use for ubuntu works flawlessly.  Did something happen during the upgrade, or is the Anaglyph plugin just incompatible with 12.04?

Comment: I am also very interested in this. Did you get any further info?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the project was re-named else discontinued. I believe this is the solution to your dilemma with 12.04. Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ddudek/stereo3d-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugin-stereo3d
```

Hope this is the answer everyone is looking for

[Link to creator's site](http://ddudek.pl/?tag=anaglyph)

Comment: p.s. There also should be an application for 12.04 called Bino which simply renders video into 3D.